# What is Query conversion for Compass query in spring Mongo template

Tags: spring-mongodb

```
My requirement is to get employees where id starts with 11 only from mongo DB.

Working query in Mongo compass for me:
{ $where: "/^11.*/.test(this.empId)" }    //succcess

but when I try to use it in Spring template using the below, it does not return result.
1st attempt:

query = new Query()
    .addCriteria(Criteria.where("/^11.*/.test(this.empId)"))
    .with(Sort.by(Sort.Direction.DESC, "empId"));


2nd Attempt
@Query(value =  "/^77.*/.test(this.empId) ",sort = "empId': -1")
```

Please advice on how to generate the above Success query through Spring.